# Can you randomly sample k values from a Dask series?

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I want to randomly sample k values without replacement from a Dask series, and I don't want to compute the length of the series beforehand. If k is larger than the length of the series, then I want to return the entire series.

I have tried the dask Series [sample function](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.sample), but it cannot handle a *delayed* object as the `frac` parameter:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0, 1, 2]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
ds = ddf["A"]

k = 2
sampled_series = ds.sample(frac=k / ds.shape[0])
sampled_series.compute()
```

gives the error

> TypeError: Trying to convert dd.Scalar<lt-3dc6..., dtype=bool> to a boolean value...

I have also tried to [sample from a dask bag](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.random.sample), but it throws an error when k is larger than the length of the bag:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0, 1, 2]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
ds = ddf["A"]

sample = random.sample(ds.to_bag(), k=4)
sample.compute()
```

gives the error

> Exception: ValueError('Sample larger than population or is negative')

Is there any way to get my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rpanai's suggestion, a sufficient solution for me is to sample from each partition. For example

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0, 1, 2]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
ds = ddf["A"]

k = 2
sampled_series = ds.map_partitions(lambda x: x.sample(n=min(k, x.shape[0]), meta=ds)
sampled_series.compute()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that `df.shape` is a delayed object and could be that this is giving you problem.

I tried this and it's working

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.arange(10)})

df =  dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

df_sampled = df.sample(frac=0.2) # I want 20% of the data
```

Comment: Thank you @rpanai for your answer. However, I want to sample a fixed number of **rows** from an arbitrary Dask Series (of any length) without computing the length of the Series before sampling. So the `frac` parameter of `.sample()` depends on `df.shape` (or the length of the data) which I don't want to compute before calling `.sample()`.

Comment: What if you take a fixed number of row from each partition? You could use map_partition in this case